# reledmac/hyperref: Can a line range abbreviation function as cross-reference?

Tags: hyperref, reledmac

We use reledmac with hyperref.

Our critical footnotes (\Xfootnote) frequently span several lines. When this is the case, we abbreviate the line range using the commands `\Xtwolines` and `\Xmorethantwolines`.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[series={A},noend,nofamiliar,noeledsec]{reledmac}

\Xtwolines{f\fullstop}
\Xmorethantwolines{ff\fullstop}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}       

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
%
\pstart
%
\edtext{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}{%
\lemma{Lorem \lbrack...\rbrack\ consequat.}
\Afootnote{A critical note that spans two or more lines.}}
%
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

With these settings, the first (and only) explicit line number in the range is made into a (colored) hyperlink, but the abbreviations are just plain text:

[image: line abbreviation without hyperlink]

"1" links back to line 1, but "ff." does not link to anything.

This is unlike the behavior of the full line range:

[image: full line range with hyperlink]

where "1" and "3" link to the *start* and *end line* respectively.

It would be nice to extend the cross referencing behavior to the abbreviation text, if possible, and have "f." or "ff." link to the *end line* of \edtext.
Especially so, since the text from `\Xmorethantwolines` can denote any number of lines, by definition, so the reader might be in doubt where the passage ends.

But I believe that there is currently no such feature of reledmac. Am I missing something?
If not, I believe this could be a useful new feature.

I get the impression that wrapping the appropriate elements in the definition of `\printlines` in, say, `\wrap@edcrossref{\@this@crossref@end}{...}` would do the job.

Maybe this could be a switch that the user can (de)activate (via `\Xlineabbreviationiscrossref` or the like).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please open a issue on github, it should be easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks, just opened an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has been added on reledmac 2.38.0, just send on CTAN. So, just update your distribution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for adding the hyperlink!